# Can rubber be used as the membrane in a diaphragm compressor with a 1:10 or higher compression ratio?

Tags: material-science, compressors, compressed-gases

I've been investing time learning about [diaphragm compressors](https://www.tacmina.com/learn/basics/21.html) and I can't understand how this particular type of compressor can have a [20:1 compression ratio](https://www-eng.lbl.gov/%7Eshuman/NEXT/GAS_SYS/diaphragmcompressor10-02_hofer.pdf), and what material could stretch that much without tearing/breaking. More specifically, I can't work out if [vulcanised rubber](https://monroeengineering.com/blog/what-is-vulcanized-rubber/#:%7E:text=Vulcanized%20rubber%20is%20both%20strong,of%20damage%20due%20to%20scraping.) (or any of it's varieties) can be used as the membrane/diaphragm, especially since looking at this diagram normal rubber doesn't have near enough [elasticity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_elasticity).

Can rubber, or any of it's vulcanised variants, be used as the membrane in a diaphragm compressor (or diaphragm pump) where there is the need for more than a 10:1 compression ratio?

Comment: this would make more sense to you if you consider a very over-square cylinder, which requires only a very short stroke.  But your own link says it uses metallic diaphragms.

Comment: @TigerGuy I'm aware that the second link references a metal membrane/diaphragm head, but that still doesn't answer the question of whether rubber could be used as a substitute, especially up to a particular pressure

Comment: Volume ratio is not a delta P since even with an ideal gas, temperature leaves an unconstrained dimension to play with.  Lots of creative ways to use geometry to get a large change in volume.  Have you ever seen an accordion? Rubber tends to be helpful to seal.  In your question there is no limit to the thickness of rubber so it is highly likely to be doable, especially since you have not constrained the forces needed to compress that rubber+air structure.